# Slater's Condition and Primal Optimal Value

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I know that Slater's condition implies strong duality and that the dual problem's supremum is attained.  Is the infimum for the primal also attained under Slater's condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no reason to be. For example, if you minimize $y$ subject to $y \ge e^x$ (that is, $e^x-y \le 0$) then the infimum is not attained; however, a point like $(0,2)$ shows that Slater's condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example!